# ByteBuffer wrap() equivalente en swift

Tags: swift2

Alguien sabe cual es el equivalente de este codigo java en swift 2.3

```
ByteBuffer tmpCounter = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteCounter);
System.out.println(tmpCounter.getLong());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno ya lo resolvi el equivalente al byteByffer.wrap() seria en swift lo siguiente.

```
 // Algoritmo equivalente a byteBuffer.wrap() de java
    let array : [UInt8] =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,62,62]; // tu array of bytes
    var value : Int = 0;
    for byte in array {
        value = value << 8;
        value = value | Int(byte);
    }
print(value);
```